# Inheritance of dynamically added methods

Tags: python, class

I have the following class `ClassA`, for which I dynamically create a method returning `string` version of another method:

```
# module_a.py
class ClassA(object):

    def width(self):
        return 5

    def height(self):
        return 10

    @classmethod
    def add_str_method(cls, name):
        method = getattr(cls, name)
        def str_method(self):
            return str(method(self))
        setattr(cls, '{0}_str'.format(name), str_method)

for name in ['width', 'height']:
    ClassA.add_str_method(name)
```

This part works perfectly fine as long as I don't subclass `ClassA` in a different module. But when I do, like in the example below, the dynamically added methods are not inherited.

```
# module_b.py
from module_a import ClassA

class ClassB(ClassA):
    pass
```

What would be the proper way of adding methods dynamically such that they are automatically inherited by subclasses?

Comment: I tried running your first block of code, but I get the following error: `TypeError: unbound method add_str_method() must be called with ClassA instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the code. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Your updated question works as expected for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to declare `add_str_method` as a `@classmethod` if you want to update the class `A` dynamically (not just an instance of `A`).

```
# file a.py

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a=5):
        self._a = a

    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @classmethod
    def add_str_method(cls, name):
        def str_method(self):
            return str(getattr(self, name)())
        setattr(cls, '{0}_str'.format(name), str_method)

for name in ['a']:
    A.add_str_method(name)
```

In order to access the `a` method from `A`, and thus the variable `_a` attached to a particular instance, the `str` method has to be bounded to `self`, note this lines:

```
def str_method(self):
    return str(getattr(self, name)())
```

Now, with this testing script it works as expected:

```
# file b.py
from a import A

class B(A):
    pass

print(B(10).a_str()) # prints '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the procedure to the initialization (`__init__`) of `classA`:

```
class ClassA(object):

    def __init__(self):
        for name in ['width', 'height']:
            self.add_str_method(name)

    def width(self):
        return 5

    def height(self):
        return 10

    def add_str_method(cls, name):
        method = getattr(self, name)
        def str_method(self):
            return str(method())
        setattr(cls, '{0}_str'.format(name), str_method)
```

Now doing

```
from module_a import ClassA

class ClassB(ClassA):
    pass

print(dir(ClassB))
```

Gives:

```
>>> ...  'height', 'width']
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. But I believe there must be a better way. For instance, if I would initialise 1M objects, each of them would add those methods on initialisation, instead of doing it once at the class level.

Furthermore, it can be useful to define class methods in a similar way, which can't be done in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: Understood. This was somewhat vague in your question though. From the scheme above one could also decide to make `name` an input argument. Then you can control initializing.